# difference in meaning of really and deadly

Tags: meaning

What problems of meaning might the following words present to a learner of English?
**really** and **deadly**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Deadly can be the synonym of extremely.

> Philosophy class was deadly boring

Philosophy class was extremely boring!

- Really is usually used to add strength, to add seriousness:

> I really want to play tennis

You want to play tennis so bad!

So deadly is to express a strong feeling, something extreme; really is to add strength.

Comment: It's also possible to use 'really' to mean 'extremely' though, in that case it is almost an exact synonym for 'deadly'. Think of the sentences "Philosophy class was really boring." However there are cases where 'deadly' cannot be used for 'extemely'. Think of the sentence "Venus Williams is really good at tennis."

Comment: Yes but extremely is stronger than really, of course you can say that

Comment: I disagree that 'extremely' is stronger than 'really'. To me 'really boring' means 'as boring as it gets'. 'Extremely' is more formal, both 'really' and 'deadly' are less formal synonyms of it.